# Python Plot issues

Tags: python, plot

I wrote this code, but the graph I end up with is a big block. What did I do wrong ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def thermal_equation(t0, tm, x, delta,w, total_time):
    t = np.linspace(0, total_time, total_time)
    temp = t0 + tm*np.exp(-x/delta)*np.cos(w*t-(x/delta))
    return t, temp

x, y = thermal_equation(28, 38, 4*10e-2, 9.1*10e-1,9.7*10e-2, 232920)

plt.plot(x, y, label='temperature fluctuation')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('temperature (c)')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

I don't know if my issue is the numbers i chose or if it is the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `total_time` parameter's value, i.e. `232920`, which is too big.

Try using a smaller value, e.g. 10. In this case you'll get a line as expected:

[image]

If you set `total_time` to 100, the plot looks like this:

[image]

And then eventually, if you set `total_time` to 1000, the plot will look like this:

[image]

where you see that the plot gets denser. Increasing `total_time`'s value results in the "big block" effect you observe. Feel free to tune the other parameters too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is actually the numbers you chose. Specifically, the values you used for delta and w are very small compared to the other values in the equation. This causes the cosine term to oscillate very rapidly, which can make it seem like the graph is just a block.

To fix this, you can try increasing the values of delta and w, or decreasing the total time total_time. For example, you could try:

```
x, y = thermal_equation(28, 38, 4*10e-2, 9.1*10e-1,9.7*10e-1, 1000)
```

This will use a larger value for w and a smaller value for total_time, which should result in a more visible temperature fluctuation over time.